# Play: stop WebSocket actor in case of failure

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka

I'm using Play framework and Akka actors for WebSocket communication. I'm using tryAcceptWithActor method:

```
def socket = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[String, String] { request =>
  Future.successful(request.session.get("user") match {
    case None => Left(Forbidden)
    case Some(_) => Right(MyWebSocketActor.props)
  })
}
```

I would like MyWebSocketActor to Stop when it fails (e.g. throwing an Exception). Is this the default supervisor strategy?
Otherwise how can I define a strategy like this? (I don't know if MyWebSocketActor are created as top-level actors or children of some actor hidden by Play)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code of `WebSocketActorSupervisor`, which is where the `Props` is converted to actor, has default strategy overridden as

```
 override def supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
  case _ => SupervisorStrategy.Stop
}
```

So, `Stop` is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To assure yourself that Johny's answer is correct override the postStop method of MyWebSocketActor. You will see that it is called when the web-socket is lost.

```
override def postStop() = {
    super.postStop()
    log.debug("connection lost")
  }
```

This is also a helpful hook for any additional handlers e.g. user presence information.